# Mysql connection timeout issue

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I have developed category vise search funcionality for virtumart (Joomla) in front side.
It is working fine on our local server but when i uploaded on server it is giving me mysql connection timeout error. It shows me like below,

```
Attention no standard shopper group set MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT * FROM `sxrth_virtuemart_shoppergroups` WHERE `default` = "2" AND (`virtuemart_vendor_id` = "1" OR `shared` = "1") AND `published`="1"
Attention no standard shopper group set MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT * FROM `sxrth_virtuemart_shoppergroups` WHERE `default` = "2" AND (`virtuemart_vendor_id` = "1" OR `shared` = "1") AND `published`="1"
```

> No Shop Currency defined! Go to http://www.domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=user&task=editshop
>   (I already apply currency and List of accepted currencies for virtuemart for this link)

I tried several option like

```
set_time_limit(o);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 14400);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 14400);
```

but that is not work for me.

I also made php.ini file in publc_html folder. It looks like below

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off
mysql.connect_timeout = 600
mysql.default_socket = 600
expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 600

max_execution_time 600
memory_limit = 360M
```

Still that is not working for me

Which actions should i have to apply to getting solution?

Comment: Error `MySQL server has gone away` mean that you have some long operations between MySQL queries. For example if you run 1 MySQL query, sleep some minutes (see default connection timeout in MySQL INI file) and run second MySQL query you get this error. So, you must find this long place and fix it. Or do reconnect to MySQL after long action.

Comment: Should i have to on mysql reconnect in php.ini file ?

Comment: Multitenant MySQL servers at hosting providers like Go Daddy sometimes impose query-duration limits on customer queries (to pack more customers onto less hardware). The server disconnects from the client when the duration runs out. They also limit `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` settings, to far less than what you have tried to set. Is it possible this is what you're seeing?

Comment: #Ollie Jones Can you please tell me how can i solve this issue ? What action should i have to take now ?

Comment: I tried mysqli.reconnect = On but it does't show any reflection in phpinfo.

Comment: The diagnosis of your problem is not completely clear from your question, so suggesting ways to fix it is difficult. If you run the offending queries from phpMyAdmin, how long do they take to complete?  What does the php code around your failing queries look like? What indexes does your table have?  Have you asked GoDaddy support for any assistance? Have you considered a higher-quality service provider?

Comment: MySQL default socket = 600?  Really? Usually it's 3306.

Comment: #Ollie Jones I tried in mysql for this query. It is taking around 25sec.

Comment: I tried with 3306 then i changed that port again.

Comment: No option exist `mysqli.reconnect`. You must do reconnect on your PHP code (use `PDO` or `MysqlI`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works me after doing `mysqli_reconnect`  and given indexing to particular fields.